What are the properties of sphingomyelins?
What are the main properties of sphingomyelins? In particular, what is the difference with typical phospholipids?
If phospholipids could do the job of sphingomyelins, there would be no evolutionary pressure to develop the additional biochemical pathway to build sphingomyelins, thus these molecules must have some specific properties that are missing in phospholipids.
Is it just the electrical insulation or is there more to it?
Thank you
